# Unique extension of (potentially noncontinuous) linear operators to the closure of the domain

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a vector subspace of a Banach space $X$ and fix a (potentially noncontinuous) linear functional $$T: V\to \mathbf{R}.$$

> **Question.** Is it true that there exists a unique (potentially noncontinuous) extension of $T$ to a linear functional $$\tilde{T}: \overline{V} \to \mathbf{R}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extension always exists, but it's not unique unless $V=\overline V$ (ie, it's not unique unless $V$ is closed). In fact

> > If $X,Y,Z$ are vector spaces, $X\subset Y$, and $T:X\to Z$ is linear then there exists a linear *extension* of $T$ to $S:Y\to Z$.

Hint: Let $B_X$ be a (Hamel) basis for $X$. Since $B_X$ is an independent subset of $Y$ there exists $B_Y$, a basis for $Y$, with $B_X\subset B_Y$.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Yes. I was thinking about extending $T$ from $V$ to $X$; since we're actually talking about extending it to $\overline V$ of course the relevant condition is $V=\overline V$.